# Is it safe to use `rax` to `jmp` to a function?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly, calling-convention

Hi I've met a situation that would need to pass parameters into functions that is predefined like the following:

```c
void dojmp(args...)
{
    args[0]->func(args...);
}
```

Instead of writing multiple jumping functions to pass different parameters, I would like to use a naked jump, so that after jumping, the relative stack and register data were not changed. Like the following.

```c
void __attribute__((naked)) dojmp(void)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__    (   
        "jmp %%rax  \n\t"
        :
        :"a"(args[0]->func)
        :"memory"                   
    );
}
```

And the gcc compiled result is:

```
<dojmp>:
  mov    %rdi,%rax
  mov    (%rax),%rax
  jmpq   *%rax
```

Now my question is that if it is safe for using `rax` as jumping target (for gcc) with `void` return function??

Since normally `rax` would be storing returning value. But all of the function I'm calling is void....

---

Just remembering it here for passing the relative address into an assembly code, in case I messed up with my notes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t)&((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)


struct have_func{
    int a;
    void* func;
};

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}

void __attribute__((naked)) dojmp(struct have_func * args)
{
    asm volatile(
        "jmpq *%P0(%%rdi)\n\t" 
        :
        : "i"(offsetof(struct have_func, func))
    );
}
```

Comment: And BTW, `$rax` is an immediate operand whose address is that of `extern char rax[]` or whatever, not the register `%rax`.

Comment: Are you going to fix the `$rax` in your title and other text?  And especially in the first code block, unless you really did mean `$rax` instead of `%%rax`.  You made an edit without fixing it, which is weird.  Also, the GCC manual explicitly warns that your `"i"(offsetof(...))` is not officially supported.  It's probably safe in practice, or at least would break in obvious ways, in that simple `naked` function, but I quoted it in my updated answer.  That's why I didn't already use that in my answer, and suggested static_assert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need inline asm for this.  **Calling this wrapper function should be exactly equivalent to casting a function pointer to the same prototype as you use for the wrapper.**  (In terms of arg-passing to the target function.)

---

Remember that the RAX return-value register isn't written by the function until *after* you've jumped to it, so yes of course it's fine to use RAX as a temporary *before* a tailcall, even to a function with a return value.  That's not a problem.  You mess with RAX, then the function runs, then it returns to your caller.

However, x86-64 System V does use AL for variadic functions to pass the count of XMM register arg.  Stepping on that is problematic if your functions actually are variadic, using `void foo(arg a, ...)` with a literal `...` in the actual C source.  Then AL needs to be passed through (for efficiency in modern implementations, and for correctness in the general case including older GCC code-gen that would use AL for a computed-jump into a sequence of `movdqa` stores.)

**It's technically not safe or supported to use Extended Asm in a `naked` function anyway** (because handing the operands involves compiler-generated code).  So your best bet for multiple reasons is to use a memory-indirect jump instead of asking the compiler to load for you:

```
 asm( "jmpq *(%rdi)" );
```

That hard-codes `offsetof(args, func)` as 0, so you can static_assert on that (or wherever in the struct you put it).

Using Extended Asm like `"i"(offsetof(..))` or `"m"(args[0]->func)` may work but is technically not supported in [a `naked` function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html).  (Because it's Extended asm).

> This attribute allows the compiler to construct the requisite function declaration, while allowing the body of the function to be assembly code. The specified function will not have prologue/epilogue sequences generated by the compiler. Only basic asm statements can safely be included in naked functions (see Basic Asm). **While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.**

---

Introducing this extra indirection (and defeating inlining) in the compiler-generated asm just to keep the compiler happy about function types kinda sucks.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Better if you can avoid inline asm entirely, although that might come at the cost of using a variadic function-pointer type but actually pointing it at non-variadic functions. x86-64 System V may handle this well enough, at least if none of the args end up default-promoted when you need them not to be.

```
args[0]->func(args, ...)
```

e.g.

```
  void (*arg0func)(struct Arg, ...) = ( void (*)(struct Arg, ...) )args[0]->func;
  arg0func(args, whatever you were going to pass);
```

You can wrap that with a CPP macro.

There might even be a way to write a variadic function that can inline and forward all its args on to another function.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! And it is really stupid of me of not noticing using `rdi` as jumping register. And furthermore, the offset address is set once struct is defined, so may I ask if it is possible to pass it into the assembly code with the rdi version~~

Comment: Hi I seems to found a way, lol~~~ really thanks for your answer~~

Comment: @Shore: Your best bet may just be to make sure the `func` member is first, so it's always at offset `0`.  Without using Extended Asm, there's no way to pass it in.  It's probably fine to use Extended Asm with an `"i"` constraint, though, even if officially unsupported.  Otherwise, you can only get C preprocessor constants into Basic Asm statements, and `offsetof` isn't.

Comment: And BTW, you might be tempted to `call` from an asm statement that can inline (not in a `naked` function).  That's a huge can of worms to open because you'd have to declare clobbers on every register, including XMM0..15, ZMM0..31, and you'd have to avoid the red-zone...   Or do a `jmp` in an asm statement in a function that can inline: but then you'd need `__builtin_unreachable()` after the asm to tell GCC that the asm statement doesn't return.  And of course, only a `naked` function gets the compiler to put args in arg-passing registers.  (or calling through a func pointer.)

Comment: Hi, the caller and the function is not in my control...... The background for this is to do an shifter that would be flexible enough to redirecting varies function calls. To be honest if I can modify the source of the caller, I will simply use an function pointer...